# onChange in form_dropdown codeigniter not work

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i try to submit a form without submit button with javascript but not work. My code is:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('week_id',$weeklist,'onChange="submitform();"','class ="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn-danger"'); ?>
```

and the js is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitform() {
 document.autosubmit.submit();
 }
```

The name and the id of the form is autosubmit. Also i will try to put the week_id inside the function but not work too. Any suggestions? Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use an ID:

```
document.querySelector('#autosubmit').submit();
```

If you just want to target the form, you need to use the `name=""` attribute, not the `id=""` attribute, something like this:

```
document.forms['autosubmit'].submit();
```